# Office 365 Api c# Windows Service

Tags: c#, api, office365, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to use the Office 365 api inside a Windows Service to link e-mails to in-house projects.

I've been able to authenticate myself using the [Office 365 API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#Getmessages)

Although I have some problems/questions.
First problem: 
`await outlookClient.Me.Folders["inbox"].Messages.ExecuteAsync();`
Isn't working for me, I don't get any response, even after 5 min...

Another question is:
Is it possible to never ask for the office365 credentials when starting the program?
Because this is running in a windows Service.

Did anybody successfully implement this?
If so: Is it possible to get a full working example?
I've been trying different things now, but much examples are for asp.net of other where an authentication is always required.

Comment: Was this issue resolved? I'm getting the same error while calling the Office365 API. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I was successfull in doing this. But it's been a while and I cannot recall how I fixed it, sorry :( I also don't have the source code to see how I did it. (Was a one  time thing)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done a service specifically, but it should work if you use the [client credential auth flow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx).

That flow would give you the unattended scenario you want for a service. However, there does have to be consent at some point. The way it works with client credential flow is you would have a signup web page. An administrator from the Office 365 org would go that page and login and grant consent to your app. This would be a onetime thing. Your app would then be able to get a token silently that grants access to all mailboxes in the organization.

Comment: Oké, this information is helpfull.
But is there any way to get me a c# example to use the connection because i'm relatively new to authentication

Comment: I made a console application, easily converted to a service, that fetches stuff from office365 calendars without direct user consent. But the authentication procedure is cumbersome. You need a x509 certificate from the office365 administrator. Using that, you can acquire an OAuth token from AD. The token is then used to fetch stuff from office365. I strongly advice you to use the ADAL library to handle the OAuth tokens.

Comment: Babu,
I've now been able to get a token from X509 certificate, using app-only. (Certificate...)
But when I use that token for requesting my messages I get: Forbidden error.
reason="OAuth2 AccessTokens for app-only require that the target mailbox is explicitly specified with the api call"

Is it possible to maybe share your console application so I can see what i'm doing wrong??

Comment: You need to not use the outlookClient.Me construct, and instead specify the user's identity like client.Users["user@contoso.com"].